# Three user inputs three global variables

Tags: python, function

I’m having problems with changing my global variables within my function, which also uses user input and (too many) if statements to do so. I keep getting the same error but at different points if I change something.

```
m=0.0
AH=1.0
ndays=0.0
Day_Count = (ndays," day out of 90")
def AtomicHabits():

   wo = input("Did you work out? Y/N? ")

   tr = input("Did you study/practice trading? Y/N?")

   co = input("Practice coding? Y/N?")

   if (wo=='y'):
    m=m+1
   if (tr=='y'):
    m=m+1
   if (co=='y'):
    m=m+1
   if (m==3):
    m=.01
   elif (m==2):
    m=.0066
   elif (m==1):
    m=.0033
   elif (m==0):
    m=(-.01)

   AH=AH*(1.0+m)
   ndays=ndays+1
   return AH, m, ndays; 

AtomicHabits()

print(“Today’s change is “, m*100, “% on ”, Day_count, bringing total improvement to “, AH )
```

I’m completely lost, first time posting here so idek how to use the search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign them as global inside your function.

```
m = 0
...

def func():
    global m
    .. 
    m = 1
```

This will make m = 1

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code to something along this lines.

- Split input part
- Modularize the code to have build extensible testing on top it.

```
M = 0.0
AH = 1.0
Ndays=0.0

def check_atomic_habits(wo,tr,co):
  global M,AH,Ndays
  
  if (wo=='y'):
    M=M+1
  if (tr=='y'):
    M=M+1
  if (co=='y'):
    M=M+1
  if (M==3):
    M=.01
  elif (M==2):
    M=.0066
  elif (M==1):
    M=.0033
  elif (M==0):
    M-=-.01
  
  AH=AH*(1.0+M)
  Ndays=Ndays+1
  

def user_input():
  # Replace here
  wo = "Y" # input("Did you work out? Y/N? ")
  tr = "Y" # input("Did you study/practice trading? Y/N?")
  co = "N" # input("Practice coding? Y/N?")
  return wo,tr,co

# This is simulation for two days.
for i in range(2):
  wo,tr,co=user_input()
  check_atomic_habits(wo=wo,tr=tr,co=co)
  print(f"Today’s change is , {M*100} on {Ndays} day out of 90, bringing total improvement to {AH}" )
```

This is would generate the following o/p:

```
Today’s change is , 1.0 on 1.0 day out of 90, bringing total improvement to 1.01
Today’s change is , 1.0 on 2.0 day out of 90, bringing total improvement to 1.0201
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you could use global variables or use your variables as parameters of your function and return them

- Global variables

```
def AtomicHabits():
    global AH, m, ndays    
    ...
    
AtomicHabits()
```

- parameters of your function

```
def AtomicHabits(AH, m, ndays):
    ...
    return AH, m, ndays 
    
AH, m, ndays = AtomicHabits(AH, m, ndays)
```

I rewrote your code with a couple of changes

```
m = 0.0
AH = 1.0
ndays = 0.0

def AtomicHabits(m, AH, ndays):

    wo = input("Did you work out? Y/N? ")

    tr = input("Did you study/practice trading? Y/N?")

    co = input("Practice coding? Y/N?")

    m += [wo, tr, co].count("y")
      
    if m==0:
        m = -0.01
    else:
        m = 0.01/(3/m)
    
    AH *= 1.0 + m
   
    return m, AH, ndays + 1

m, AH, ndays = AtomicHabits(m, AH, ndays)

print(f"Today’s change is , {m*100} on {ndays} day out of 90, bringing total improvement to {AH}" )
```